# in bash, why error on history -s "- ", history -s '- '?

Tags: command-line, bash

bash version 5.2.15(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Following lines give no error message, as espected:

```
history -s "-"

history -s -- "- "
```

but following lines give error:

```
history -s "- "

history -s '- '
```

(in argument string: dash followed by BLANK)

error message is

```
bash: history: - : invalid option
```

This is as if bash would parse the argument string for a bash option.

Yet if there is a bash option, like

```
history -s "-p "
```

the option is not honored, gives the same error message

```
bash: history: - : invalid option
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

As with most shell commands and tools, `--` means "end of options". So, without a `--`, the command indeed tries to parse the arguments as its own options.

`'-p '` is not a bash option. Without `--`, as `-p` doesn't take a value, it's interpreted as two options, `-p` and `"- "`, where the second one is invalid - as reported in the error message. That's just stacking the options as you can do with `history -sp`.